# Syntax to check isset using comparison operators

Tags: php, comparison, operators

Just like how we do in other languages to check for a condition in one line. Is it possible to do it in PHP?

in java

```
boolean val = (a == b) ? true : false;
```

similarly is it possible in PHP.

If yes, the can this be done for the `isset` keyword?

Comment: BTW `val = (a == b) ? true : false` can be simplied to `val = (a == b)` :)

Comment: Note that, in your example, the `?:` operator is not necessary, since the result of `a == b` will *already be a boolean*.  It's roughly the same thing as saying `int x = y + 0;` -- the `+ 0` clause does not change the result of the expression, just like `? true : false` doesn't change the result of the `a == b` expression.  It's effectively a no-op.

Comment: Well, i tried to give that as an example for ternary operators. Thanks for your suggestions anyways @amaud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  PHP supports the `?:` ternary operator as well.  For example:

```
$foo = isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use the ternary operator in PHP. Replacing `(a == b)` with `isset(expression)` (returns boolean value) should do the trick. Just make sure that the `=` operator doesn't take precedence. It may not be necessary but I'd wrap the ternary statement in between curved brackets.